# VSCode not Recognizing Gradle Source Dependency

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

I've been playing around with gradle and multi-repository projects recently and I found out about gradle's source dependencies https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-source-dependencies. Since I thought it was interesting I've been trying to get it to work. I have managed to get a project working and building, however VSCode is yelling at me that the import cannot be resolved. I would appreciate some help figuring out a solution to this as I can't find much out there about this on the interwebs.

Repos:

- Application: https://github.com/EliSauder/robot-test/tree/e652b3670f2bb63f1224c55d346fc5c95d0b1d49
- Library: https://github.com/EliSauder/robot-lib-test/tree/noFRC

Application `settings.gradle`:

```
sourceControl {
    gitRepository("https://github.com/EliSauder/robot-lib-test.git") {
        producesModule("org.frcnomad:lib")
    }
}
```

Application `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id "application"
}

group = 'org.frcnomad'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

mainClassName = 'org.frcnomad.robot.Main'

dependencies {
    implementation('org.frcnomad:lib') {
        version {
            branch = 'noFRC'
        }
    }

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
    
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.+"
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: ‘VSCode is yelling at me that the import cannot be resolved’. what's the related package, please describe your question as clearly as possible.

Comment: @MollyWang I have the library that I developed in the robot-lib-test repository. After adding that as a source dependency in gradle, vscode is not recognizing any of the contents of the library even though I can build the project in gradle just fine.

Is that a little more clear?

Comment: No offence, but are you sure your dependency is executable and nothing wrong? The reason import can't be resolved could be 1. the dependency itself gets something wrong; 2. the information about dependency you quoted is wrong. You can try to clean java workspace first and rebuild the project. If the error still exists, check the above two aspects.

Comment: @MollyWang No offence taken :). I am sure that its executable because gradle is able to build and run it without any issues. There is nothing wrong with the code, the issue is that VSCode does not recognize the contents of the library.

I tried cleaning the workspace in vscode and am still running into the same issue. Gradle can build and run the project (including the library), but VSCode yells about the library.

Comment: This question looks really similar to [a question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67079723/14765128) a few weeks ago. Does that solution work for you?