# package org.junit doesn't exists in vscode

Tags: java, maven

I get this error **package org.junit doesn't exists in vscode** when I import
`import junit.framework.Test;` or  `import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;`

this is my test file

```
package com.wezigo.myapp.service;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MyServiceTest {
    @Test
    public void testCompute(){
        MyService service =new MyService();
        //MyService service =  new MyService();
        double a = 15;
        double b = 15;
        double expected = 20;
        double result = service.compute(a,b);
        assertEquals(expected, result,0.001 );
    }

   

   
}
```

this is pom.xml file content

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.wezigo</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>myapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

i try the solution in this address
**[Why does vscode not recognize the import org.junit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62075442/why-does-vscode-not-recognize-the-import-org-junit)
**  but i use vscode 1.60.0 and this command is not availlable **View -> Command Palette -> Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace**

when compile, i get thes error

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.083 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-24T12:10:31+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/rodolphe/javaTraining/work1). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

Comment: Does the build work on plain command line?

Comment: i get an error when compile `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project myapp: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:`

Comment: This line is useless...There are lines above that which show in detail the problem..those are interesting...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
package com.wezigo.myapp.service;

public class MyServiceTest {
    public void testCompute(){
        MyService service =new MyService();
        double a = 15;
        double b = 15;
        double expected = 20;
        double result = service.compute(a,b);
        assert Math.abs(expected - result) <= 0.001;
    }
}
```

A popular fallacy is that you need junit for unit testing.